# Using both `get` and `apply` Proxy traps on plain JS object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following code is a simple proxy that logs out the "gets" that were trapped:

```
var p = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, property, receiver) {
        console.log("getting: ", property);
        return target[property];
    }
});
```

When I coerce this into a String with `"hello " + p`, I get the following output in the console:

```
getting:  Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive)
getting:  valueOf
getting:  toString
getting:  Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
"hello [object Object]"
```

Everything is fine so far, but let's do something a little sneaky and proxy a *function*, but actually still use it as a proxy to our plain object we used in the last example. The reason I want this is because I'd like to be able to capture both `get`s and `apply`s on this `obj`.

Notice the `return target.obj` part - we're really using this to proxy `obj` still - it's just that we're doing it *via* `fn`:

```
var fn = function(){};
fn.obj = {};
var p = new Proxy(fn, {
    get: function(target, property, receiver) {
        console.log("getting: ", property);
        return target.obj[property];
    }
});
```

Now, I'd have thought this would produce exactly the same output as the last example for `"hello " + p`, but I was wrong:

```
getting:  Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive)
getting:  valueOf
getting:  toString
getting:  Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
"hello [object Function]"
```

Notice that it has resulted in a `Function` string tag rather than an `Object` one. What's going on here? It's as if `toString` is being called on `fn` rather than `obj`. (**Edit:** But we can add `fn.toString = function(){ return "fn"; }` and it doesn't change the output, so maybe it's not `fn` that is being stringified here?)

If you pop a `debugger` statement in there, you'll see it's actually returning `fn.obj.toString` as you'd expect, but for some reason the final output is a function rather than an object (though I'm not entirely sure *which* function). Thanks for your help!

P.S. I haven't explained the full context of my use case (short version: it's for a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), so bending "good practice" is fine), and so suggesting alternative patterns to achieve both `get` and `apply` traps on an object (in effect) may not be relevant to my particular case. I'd really just like to understand why the above approach isn't working like I expect it to, but would also like to ensure the question is broad enough to help future readers in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the bug. When we return a function, it looks like we need to `bind` it to `target.obj`, otherwise it's being bound to some function somewhere. I'm not completely up to scratch on `this` stuff, but I think it makes sense. So here's the updated, working code:

```
var fn = function(){};
fn.obj = {};
fn.toString = function(){ return "fn"; }
var p = new Proxy(fn, {
    get: function(target, property, receiver) {
        console.log("getting: ", property);
        let result = target.obj[property];
        if(typeof result === 'function') {
          result = result.bind(target.obj);
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Very interesting problem! Still more research to do before I understand exactly what's going on, though [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) shows why binding your this value is important.